# Where does Eclipse save WSDL file?

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I use Eclipse and Axis2 for SOAP WS.

When we create a WebService from a POJO (bottom-up), where is placed the WSDL file, in Eclipse project?

I can get it in browser at `/PROJECT/services/WEBSERVICE?wsdl`, but I'd like to customize something in it before deplying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis2 generate the WSDL document file on deployment time. By default, when you add `?wsdl`, Axis2 does not retrieve a previously generated WSDL document. It is generated every time. But if you put the WSDL document file and the corresponding XML Schema files inside the `META-INF` folder in the service archive file, it can be recovered with:

```
http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/MyService.wsdl
```

The service name given in the `services.xml` and the service name defined in the WSDL document should be the same.

Comment: Cool tnx! But what about the default URL, used in Axis2 page, the ?wsdl one? It's useless to have a custom WSDL served in other URL if the "popular" one keeps serving the dynamic WSDL.

Comment: The Axis2 servlet see the param `wsdl` in the query string.